# iOS Swift - AVPlayer embeded in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer

Is there a way to create a tableView with AVPlayer in UITableViewCell, and scroll without lag? I'm using **replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem** method to replace the item in the AVPlayer for each cell.. and it freezes at every cell dequeue......

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [AVPlayer.prerollAtRate:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/prerollAtRate:completionHandler:)?

You could display the first frame of the video while it gets ready using [AVAssetImageGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/index.html).

Comment: What does this have to do with replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem and the lags?